# OpenMap not Working in Android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, openmap

```
OpenMap not showing in Android emulator.
When I Execute `OpenMapDemo` in android emulator.

Couldn't get connection factory client

    08-04 08:10:15.933: W/System.err(1406): IOException processing: 26
    08-04 08:10:15.943: W/System.err(1406): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
    08-04 08:10:15.953: W/System.err(1406):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
    08-04 08:10:15.963: W/System.err(1406):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
```

this is Main Activity which override method on-create.On created Update Location method called.
any ideas ?

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchMapListener);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateLocation(location);
    }
      @Override
    public void updateLocation(Location loc) {
        super.updateLocation(loc);

        double myLat = Utilities.convertPointFromE6(UserData.getLatitudeE6());
        double myLon = Utilities.convertPointFromE6(UserData.getLongitudeE6());
        lastLocation = new LatLonPoint(myLat, myLon);
    }
```

Comment: plase share your code

Comment: i have used openmapdemo sample code.

Comment: did u run your app in real device??

Comment: No, i am only try to run on emulator